# File converter: from CSV to HDF5

Tags: csv

Can anyone recommend any command line tool for converting large CSV file into HDF5 format?

Comment: depending on your definition of "large", you can use:
`python -c "import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv('input_file.csv').to_hdf('output_file.hdf5', key='data')"`

Answer (score 2):

- **1st approach:** Use [append=True](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/io.html#id2) in the call to `to_hdf`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#filename = '/tmp/test.hdf5'
filename = 'D:\test.hdf5'

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)), columns=['C1', 'C2'])
print(df)
#    C1  C2
# 0  0   1
# 1  2   3
# 2  4   5
# 3  6   7

# Save to HDF5
df.to_hdf(filename, 'data', mode='w', format='table')
del df    # allow df to be garbage collected

# Append more data
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2))*10, columns=['C1', 'C2'])
df2.to_hdf(filename, 'data', append=True)

print(pd.read_hdf(filename, 'data'))
```

- **2nd approach:**  you could append to a [HDFStore](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/io.html#table-format) instead of calling `df.to_hdf`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#filename = '/tmp/test.hdf5'
filename = 'D:\test.hdf5'
store = pd.HDFStore(filename)

for i in range(2):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)) * 10**i, columns=['C1', 'C2'])
    store.append('data', df)

store.close()

store = pd.HDFStore(filename)
data = store['data']
print(data)
store.close()
```

- **3rd approach:**  using `chunksize` parameter and append each chunk to the HDF file which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620538/10452700).

Personally, I like the 1st and 2nd approaches.